# TYPO3 Extbase createAction - how to create a new IRRE relation with f:form?

Tags: forms, typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I have created an extension with the Extension Builder. With the help of the extension, an ordering process should be mapped.

An order can contain several IRRE records (quantities).
A quantity contains the desired amount and the information whether it is a single product or a menu.

In the backend everything works fine. But now I try to create a new order in the frontend via a f:form. It is not clear to me how I can assign a new IRRE relation to the order. My approach is this one, but it doesn't work. Can someone help?

I tried this:

```
<f:for each="{products}" as="product" key="key">
    <div class="product">
        <label for="product-{key}">
            <f:form.checkbox property="quantities.product" multiple="1" id="product-{key}" name="product-{key}" value="{product}" />
            {product.title}<br />
            <f:for each="{product.productvariants}" as="productvariant">
                - {productvariant.title}<br />
            </f:for>
        </label>
    </div>
</f:for>
<f:for each="{menus}" as="menu" key="key">
    <div class="menu">
        <label for="menu-{key}">
            <f:form.checkbox property="quantities.menu" multiple="1" id="menu-{key}" name="menu-{key}" value="{menu}" />
            {menu.title}
        </label>
    </div>
</f:for>
```

But i got this exeption:

```
Exception while property mapping at property path "quantities.product": The identity property "" is no UID.
```

[image: Model of Order]
[image: Frontend Form for new order]
[image: DB structure of my extension]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a custom finisher ([see docs](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/master/en-us/I/Concepts/Finishers/Index.html#write-a-custom-finisher)) and extending `\TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Finishers\SaveToDatabaseFinisher`.

If you are using the [DataHandler](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/UsingDataHandler/Index.html) for persisting instead of writing [custom sql](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/Connection/Index.html#insert) you even don't need to care about the relation handling much.